# Run thucydides with maven, skip tests

Tags: maven, jbehave, thucydides

For testing purposes i'm using Thucydides combined with Jbehave. 
Now I have a story login.story

*Scenario: Succesfull login 


Given the user is on the login page

Given the user enters his username 

Given the user enters his password 

When the user logs in

Then the user should see his name  on the homepage*


And another story story1.story that includes the login

*Meta:   @username username

        @password password

        @name name

GivenStories: Login.story*

Scenario: .....

When i run my tests with maven with the folowing command
*mvn clean verify thucydides:aggregate -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true*
  
Then maven runs all the stories.
Because login.story is just a story to be included and parameterized in other stories, i don't want it to run.   Maven runs it now and says its a pending story because it does not include any examples.

Is there a way to avoid this?  Can you tell maven which stories to run, and what is the sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-Djbehave.story.name=login` with your command [Don't use `login.story` but use `login` without extension `.story`]. It should start only one mentioned story file.